# fullcalendar scheduler only allow select in Background event

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I want to allow select only in the background event that I set. Thus, I found something in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap . However, it does not work for me.

```
events: [
    {
        id : '1',
        start: '11:00',
        end: '18:30',
        color: 'gray',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [1],
        resourceId: "jenny"
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        start: '14:30',
        end: '22:30',
        color: 'gray',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [3],
        resourceId: "tom"
    }
],
selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return event.rendering === 'background';
}
```

Even if I do this, I can still select all of the slots.

+)
Also, I tried to use businessHours, but it couldn't differentiate the resources.

```
resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'A' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'B', eventColor: 'green' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'C', eventColor: 'orange' },
            { id: 'd', title: 'D', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'e', title: 'E', eventColor: 'blue'}
        ],
        resourceAreaWidth: "10%",

        selectConstraint : "businessHours", 
         businessHours: 
         [
          {
            dow: [ 1, 2, 3 ], 
            start: '11:00', 
            end: '18:00',
            resourceId : "a" 
          },
          {
            dow: [ 4, 5 ], 
            start: '10:00', 
            end: '16:00',
            resourceId: "b" 
          }
         ]
```

I set different businessHours per resource, but the result is all same businessHour for all of resources. 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCYnO.png)

Comment: **The selectOverlap setting does not differentiate between background events or normal events. It treats both types of events the same unless you write custom logic in your callback function (like the code above).** Read the doc carefully

Comment: You mean the selection must occur _entirely within_ a background event? the "Overlap" function does exactly that, checks for overlaps. It doesn't stop selections being made which are in areas with no events - that's the standard functionality. If you want that you'll need much more custom code to stop that happening in the "select" callback itself, and check the selected area against all the events to make sure it comes within certain areas covered by the background events - you're basically asking for the opposite of the standard functionality. Maybe `businessHours` would be better for you?

Comment: @ADyson yes, I looked up businessHours. However, the problem is that I want to add multiple businessHours, but it is not working. Thus, I want to make something similar with multiple businessHours by background event.

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours you can specify multiple businessHours in an array, as long as you're using fullCalendar 2.9.1 or above. If you have an older version, I'd consider upgrading, 2.9.1 is not exactly new anyway.

Comment: @ADyson I tried that already, but it doesn't work. I am using fullcalendar scheduler 1.9.4. maybe this is the reason why that isn't work

Comment: The Scheduler and fullCalendar Core version numbers are different. If you're using Scheduler 1.9.4 then as per https://fullcalendar.io/support you should be using fullCalendar 3.9.0 or above. If you tried businessHours and it didn't work, please show us exactly the code you tried and explain what went wrong, because I would have expected it to help you.

Comment: @ADyson I added. I searched about this, and there are a lot of people who have the same problem as mine, so I guess there is something wrong in fullcalendar itself,,,

Comment: Thanks, the example makes it clearer what you're trying to do precisely. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours-per-resource shows you how to define business Hours for a specific resource. It's not done the same way. You have to set it as a property of the resource.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you! I really need to read fullcalendar docs carefully...